# Adding two navigation items to one main menu

Tags: shopify

I'm new to shopify and customizing an existing theme. I was wondering how to do the following.

I have two navigation items (in navigation section of admin):

```
COLLECTIONS
Men
Women
Kids
```

-and-

```
INSPIRATIONS
Casual
Vacation
Weekend
Business
```

Currently I have two items in my main menu corresponding to COLLECTIONS and INSPIRATIONS (with corresponding dropdowns). I was wondering how to put them both under one main item

```
SHOP--------------------------------------
COLLECTIONS         INSPIRATIONS
Men                 Casual
Women               Business
...
```

Thanks in advance
Julia

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called "Link Lists" in Shopify. This is what you need to do

1. Go to `Admin -> Navigation` and edit menu of "Main Menu"
2. Add a single item "Shop" and select "All Collections" as the link
3. Go back to "Navigation" and create a new menu "Shop"
4. Add two items "Collections" and "Inspirations"

Now you have linked "Collections" and "Inspirations" menu to a parent menu "Shop"

Note: The title of the items inside a menu should always be the same as that of the menu you want to link together.

Refer to this for more details: [Create a drop-down menu on my storefront](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-website/navigation/create-drop-down-menu)

Next comes displaying submenus inside the menu. Shopify default theme doesn't have this feature out of the box. You can refer to this Shopify thread for implementation: [Multi-level menus in Shopify](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/multi-level-menus-in-shopify-is-there-a-definitive-answer-138415). It is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this creates a nested dropdown, while what I want is single dropdown with COLLECTIONS and INSPIRATIONS as titles of two link lists.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? I may be able to understand the problem better.

Comment: I've figured it out by using megamenu. Thanks